# Tencent Bugly SDK

Tags: sdk, playback

My app on Google Play Store was suspended. The reason given was "We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Tencent Bugly SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play."

What is Tencent Bugly SDK, and what packages might contain it?

The only thing I added to my app recently was AdMob support.

Many thinks if anyone else has seen this issue and can suggest how to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

Did your app integrate with Bugly Upgrade SDK?

Bugly Upgrade SDK has hotfix feature.

and request install permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: I removed Bugly from the app. Google Play banned my app and didn't allow a fix. I had to resubmit as a new listing and product name.

Comment: @Phil Smith Do you success resubmit new package and new product name app? I have same question about bugly, when submit new package, old app can auto update new package version or out of control?

Answer (score 0):

Our product also used this hotfix feature. Can I continue to use it, but we have commented out the part used in the code.